# Attempting to set the layout to BoxLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, boxlayout

I can't seem to find a solution online for why I'm getting this error on attempted run

I'm working on making a simple test system for a different program when are button press will yield value in a text box.  I would like them to be on different lines to make it cleaner, so I looked into layouts.  I decided a Box Layout would fit me best.  I looked at different examples before attempting this and my code ended up looking like this, (apologies for the messy code)

### Update

Got the box layout error to disappear but the code will not center them on the panel/frame.  The label and button align left while the textfield becomes very large. I don't need it todo that

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;

import static javax.swing.BoxLayout.Y_AXIS;
import static javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER;

public class button extends JFrame {
static JFrame f;
static JButton b;
static JLabel l;

// main class
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // create a new frame to stor text field and button
    f = new JFrame("panel");
    BoxLayout layout = new BoxLayout(f, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
    f.setLayout(layout);

    // create a label to display text
    l = new JLabel("panel label");
    b = new JButton("button1");
    JTextField textArea = new JTextField(5);
    textArea.setEditable(false);
    //textArea.append("Hello World");


    // create a panel to add buttons
    JPanel p = new JPanel();

    // add buttons and textfield to panel
    f.add(p);
    f.setSize(300, 300);
    p.add(l);
    p.add(b);
    p.setBackground(Color.white);
    p.add(textArea);
    f.show();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            Random r = new Random();
            textArea.setText(String.valueOf(r));

        }
    });
}
}






Error
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.AWTError: BoxLayout can't be shared
at java.desktop/javax.swing.BoxLayout.checkContainer(BoxLayout.java:461)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.BoxLayout.invalidateLayout(BoxLayout.java:245)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.BoxLayout.addLayoutComponent(BoxLayout.java:278)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1152)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:1029)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JFrame.addImpl(JFrame.java:553)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:436)
at button.main(button.java:36)
```

I would like the three items to all to be stacked one on top of another with a space between them.  The order doesn't matter right now.

Comment: You said you were "getting this error"; but it's not all all clear what "this error" is. Please clarify.

Comment: Set the `BoxLayout` as the layout manager for the `JPanel`, _p_, and not for the `JFrame`

Comment: *I looked at different examples* - the best source for examples is the Oracle [Swing Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) for all Swing basics in one place. The section on `How to Use BoxLayout` has working code for you to download and test. This code should be the starting point as it also demonstrates a better way to structure your code. For example you should NOT 1) extend JFrame 2) use static variables. You SHOULD 1) create the GUI on the Event Dispatch Thread.

Answer (score 3):

*Swing* was first added to the JDK in 1998 and has undergone a lot of changes since. Unfortunately, when you read Web pages about *Swing*, it is not obvious when that page was last updated. Consequently you may be learning outdated techniques for writing *Swing* code.

First of all, according to the code you posted, class `button` does not need to extend class `JFrame` since you use a static variable as your application's `JFrame`. Also, `JFrame` is a top-level container which makes it a special kind of container and not the same kind of continer as a `JPanel`. You need to set the layout manager for your `JPanel` and then add the `JLabel`, `JTextField` and `JButton` to that `JPanel`. And then add the `JPanel` to the `JFrame`.

Calling method `pack()` of class `JFrame` will automatically set the preferred sizes for the components inside the `JFrame`. It appears in the code below.

Please also look at [Java coding conventions](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html) which allows others to more easily read and understand your code. And note that, according to these conventions, I renamed your class from `button` to `Buttons` and also because there are already several class in the JDK named `Button`.

Here is my rewrite of your code...

```java
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class Buttons implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        createAndShowGui();
    }

    private void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Box");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        BoxLayout layout = new BoxLayout(p, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
        p.setLayout(layout);
        JLabel l = new JLabel("panel label");
        JTextField textField = new JTextField(5);
        JButton b = new JButton("button1");
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                Random r = new Random();
                textField.setText(String.valueOf(r.nextBoolean()));
            }
        });
        p.add(l);
        p.add(textField);
        p.add(b);
        f.add(p);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Buttons instance = new Buttons();
        EventQueue.invokeLater(instance);
    }
}
```

Comment: *Consequently you may be learning outdated techniques for writing Swing code.* - so the best place to start is the [Swing Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) as it contains example for most Swing basics, including the section on `How to Use a BoxLayout`.